# Angular2 make textarea press enter without new line added

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a textarea for some text input.
When user finish typing, I let them use [Enter] to confirm the text by

```
<textarea #msgInput (keyup.enter)="confirmText(msgInput.value)" >
</textarea>
```

Although i can successfully get the text inside confirmText().
A newline is created on the value of the textarea.

How do I drop the new-line char to the textarea correctly?
I know there exist some method like return 0 and preventDefault() when writing js but I have no idea how to do it in Angular2 typescript.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add a `;false` to the expression to suppress default behavior:

```
<textarea #msgInput (keydown.enter)="confirmText(msgInput.value);false" >
```

You also have to use `keydown` instead of `keyup` because cancelling on `keyup` is too late.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/d1hdT2?p=preview)

Comment: Note, "cancelling on keyup is too late" was incredibly useful in diagnosing prevent default on @HostListener in Angular 8.